# iphone embedded internet radio streaming?

Tags: iphone, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I need to build an iPhone app with the ability to stream internet radio.

Can someone please tell me what formats I need to cover or possibly direct me to an open source project to help me do this?

I know that quick time player on iphone supports a number of formats, but I need to wite my own embedded player inside the app, so that the user can be streaming media while working on a different view in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came accros this monotouch sample one day (programming iPhone with .net). You will find api calls in the source code:

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/StreamingAudio

Comment: interesting app. thanks for the response. handles creative commons mp3. good start... need to checkout the other formats now.

Comment: Have a look at the MediaPlayer class maybe. Just a guess, I never developer on the iPhone